# malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion ... failed

Tags: c++, vector, heap-corruption

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on.  Here's the error I get:

```
alloc static vecs
a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)
```

The error occurs in the function `Halton` in class `qmc`, which I've included the relevant bits to below.  As you can see, the first print statement "alloc static vecs" executes, but the statement `std::vector<double> H(s);` appears not to, since the print statement immediately following it does not execute.

Now, I should mention that when I replace the statement `static std::vector<int> bases = FirstPrimes(s);` in `Halton` with `static std::vector<int> bases = {2,3,5,7,11,13};` (the RHS is the return array of `FirstPrimes()`, just hardcoded) then there is no error.

There are more functions in `Halton` (it returns a `std::vector`) but I've omitted them for brevity.  I'll add them if anyone wants to try to run it themselves, just ask!

I'm using g++ 4.6 and Ubuntu 12.04, and the compilation command is `g++ -std=c++0x scratch.cpp QMC.cpp`.

main (scratch.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "QMC.h"

int main() {
  QMC qmc;

  std::vector<double> halton = qmc.Halton(6,1);
}
```

QMC.h:

```
#ifndef QMC_H
#define QMC_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>                                 
#include <vector>

class QMC {
 public:
  QMC();
  bool isPrime(int n);
  std::vector<int> ChangeBase(int n, int radix);
  std::vector<int> NextChangeBase(std::vector<int>& a_in, int radix);
  double RadicalInverse(std::vector<int>& a, int b);
  std::vector<int> FirstPrimes(int n);
  std::vector<double> Halton(int s, int n = 0);
};
#endif
```

QMC.cpp:

```
#include "QMC.h"

QMC::QMC(){}

std::vector<double> QMC::Halton(int s, int n) {
  static std::vector<std::vector<int> > newBases(s);
  static std::vector<int> bases = FirstPrimes(s);

  /* replacing the statement immediately above with 
     static std::vector<int> bases = {2,3,5,7,11,13}; fixes it */

  std::cout << "alloc static vecs \n";

  std::vector<double> H(s);

  std::cout << "alloc H \n";

  // ...there's more to this function, but the error occurs just above this.
}

std::vector<int> QMC::FirstPrimes(int n) {

  std::vector<int> primes(n);
  primes[0] = 2;

  int testNum = 3;

  for (int countOfPrimes = 1; countOfPrimes <= n; ++countOfPrimes) {
    while (isPrime(testNum) == false)
      testNum = testNum + 2;

    primes[countOfPrimes] = testNum;
    testNum = testNum + 2;
   }

  return primes;
}

bool QMC::isPrime(int n) {
  if (n == 1) return false;  // 1 is not prime                                                                                                   
  else if (n < 4) return true;  // 2 & 3 are prime                                                                                               
  else if (n % 2 == 0) return false; // even numbers are not prime                                                                               
  else if (n < 9) return true; // 5 & 7 are prime                                                                                                
  else if (n % 3 == 0) return false;  // multiples of 3 (> 3) are not prime                                                                      
  else
    {
      int r = floor(sqrt((double)n));
      int f = 5;

      while (f <= r)
        {
          if (n % f == 0) return false;
          if (n % (f + 2) == 0) return false;
          f += 6;
        }

      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb Just did that, and yes, I still get the error :/

Comment: When you write a loop's condition to keep the loop going, and you find yourself using <=, take another look at the loop.  `countOfPrimes <= n`.  When I see this, and I see that countOfPrimes or whatever the variable happens to be is used as an index, that sets off a red flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstPrimes` has a buffer overflow. The relevant lines:

```
std::vector<int> primes(n);
primes[0] = 2;

for (int countOfPrimes = 1; countOfPrimes <= n; ++countOfPrimes)
   primes[countOfPrimes] = testNum;
```

For a vector of size `n`, the valud indices are `0` through `n-1`. On the last loop iteration you do an out-of-bounds access.

I'd suggest changing both of the `[ ]` to `.at( )`, as well as fixing the logic error. This would also prevent trouble if you happened to call this function with `n == 0`.

Comment: Nice!  Good looking out.  What's strange is that this error just started today, and I've used this code for about a month with no problem.  I'd be interested to know why!

Comment: Just luck with what happened to be in memory after that vector, I guess

Comment: @bcf - When you overrun a buffer, anything can happen.  The program may run successfully for 3 or 4 times straight, then when run again, crashes.  Or run a thousand times on your machine, but as soon as you run it on another machine, crashes right away.

Comment: I generally refer to buffer overflows as ticking time bombs. They're going to explode at some point in the future... But you often don't know when.